# Print values nicely in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

Haskell's `ghci` can print nicely any value belonging to a type that implements `Show` typeclass. Is there any equivalent in OCaml that lets `utop` automatically print values of user-defined types nicely? Typing `x |> M.to_string` every line is quite tedious…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module for your type `M.t` define the function:

```
val pp : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
```

You can then install a printer for the type in `ocaml` or `utop` using:

```
# #install_printer M.pp
```

See the [toplevel directive](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec275) section of the manual.

Comment: That seems to work for me, but how can I use this `Format.formatter` value in this function. When I wrote naively: `let pp _ r = to_string r |> print_string`, I got output before type signature instead of after `=`. The Format module documentation does not help me much…

Comment: Okay, I've found it on my own: there's `val pp_print_text : formatter -> string -> unit` function in `Format` module which does exactly what's expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one comment about your first try. You cannot do that you need to hook in the format system abstraction you cannot just print output by your own in pretty printing functions.